# Is it possible to get a file on my host in order to be used by a chaincode in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode, chaincode

I'm working on Hyperledger Fabric and I'd like to know if it is possible to save a text file on my host that will be retrieved by the chaincode to be used. In this way I would obtain data resisting to procedures of restarting and anytime it is required, I could use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have data in file on local disk and read it in chaincode, but remember chain code executes on every peer, and so the file would be read by each peer, not just once. Imagine you have 2 orgs and 3 peers per org, then we have 6 peers in total. So, this means that if you wrote a code to read the file, the file would be read by each peer once, i.e six times (assuming all peers are on same box).

Static data which can be read from file is best fed to chain code as parameters to avoid a file being read multiple times. This can easily cause resource contention (disk chokes and whole system performance goes down).